# AS2: Instance name length effecting hitTest?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I run a hitTest against thousands of MCs at a time, they have relatively large number names (9 figure), right now I use these numbers for something else but I was wondering if I found a different solution could this possibly free up much flash memory?

Would hitTesting against shorter instance names (considering I have almost 3000 of these MovieClips being hitTested at once) would it cause a visible change in performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

length of variable names does not affect the performance of your code.

think about rewriting other aspects of your code: like loops etc ...
check these out: [actionscript 3 optimizations](http://je2050.joa-ebert.com/files/misc/as3opt.pdf) by joa ebert